# How to read and write RFID tags in React PWA

Tags: reactjs, frontend, progressive-web-apps, rfid

As above, I have an RFID reader and card and I would like React PWA to listen to this reader. How can this be done?

Comment: To read/write an RFID you will need some driver to talk with. How do you think to talk with this driver from a site that runs on a browser?

Comment: I'm sorry but I forgot to mention that it will be PWA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case someone was looking for an answer to this question, below I will describe how I did it. I used a reader that mimics keyboard input and just listened to the keyboard in app. It worked without a problem.